# Variable String is null

Tags: android, facebook, android-volley

I would like to know why a global String variable is null after calling a method.

My code is:

```
public void login_fb()
{

    final Funciones f = (Funciones) getApplication();

   fbloginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {

            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                        {


                            try
                            {
                                correofb = object.getString("email");

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parametros = new Bundle();
            parametros.putString("fields","email");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parametros);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();


            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginTienda.this,Comprador_registrado.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error)
        {
            String msgerror = error.getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(LoginTienda.this, msgerror, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile)
        {


            if(currentProfile == null)
            {
                f.borrar_sp();

                Intent i = new Intent(LoginTienda.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {

                existe_correo_fb();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),usr_correo_existe,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //the value of usr_correo is null here
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),correofb,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                f.insertar_sp("usrcorreo",correofb);
                f.insertar_sp("usrnombre",nombrefb);
                f.insertar_sp("usrapellido",apellidofb);
                f.insertar_sp("reg","fb");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

From login_fb() I call existe_correo_fb(). Both methods use a global variable named usr_correo_existe that is declared at the beginning of the activity.

The value of usr_correo_existe is assigned in the existe_correo_fb(). From this method the value of usr_correo_existe is right, but if I check the same value in the login_fb() method the value is null. And I don't know why. I think the value should be the same as in other method because the usr_correo_existe is a global variable.

The code of existe_correo_fb() method:

```
public void existe_correo_fb()
{

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),correofb,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.CORREO_RS_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()

            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {

                    usr_correo_existe = response; //the value of usr_correo_existe is assigned and right here

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),usr_correo_existe,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Error)
                {

                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "No se ha podido hacer la conexión", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();


            params.put("correo",correofb);


            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginTienda.this);


    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

The declaration of the usr_correo_existe:

```
public class LoginTienda extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private String usr_correo_existe;

}
```

How can I watch the right value of usr_correo_existe variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you have  error in your code ?And could you put your detail code here?

Comment: If it's an error is not a runtimeerror or something like that because I can create the apk correctly.

Comment: Problem fixed. I change the structure of the activity and it works now. The problem was the else of onCurrentProfileChanged method is never run.